# Is there a way to get a an integer stored in memory output in lldb having a watch point

Tags: xcode, debugging, integer, output, lldb

Is there a way to get a an integer stored in memory x8 00000....21 output in lldb having a watch point on ex: 0x000000010092e1b4 without stoping the app

(i am trying to read a live int value from an IOS app)

Answer (score 2):

You can set a watchpoint on an address (and specify a size), and add a command on that watchpoint to be executed every time the watchpoint is hit.  For instance, this will print `variable` every time the watchpoint is hit.

```
(lldb) wa se e -s 8 -- 0x000000010092e1b4
(lldb) wa comm add 
Enter your debugger command(s).  Type 'DONE' to end.
> p variable
> c 
> DONE
(lldb)
```